# Converting string encoding so it displays accents

Tags: php

In php I have strings such as:

> Independ%C3%AAncia

and I want to convert it to:

> Indepêndencia

Checking the encode php says it is ACSII which is a subset of UTF8.
So how can I make that conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php):

```
php > echo urldecode('Independ%C3%AAncia');
Independência
php >
```